# Error when importing data to DolphinDB with DataX

Tags: import, analytics, dolphindb

To import data to DolphinDB with DataX (DATAX-OPENSOURCE-3.0) and DolphinDBWriter (130.21.5), I add the following script to the configuration JSON file:

```
"saveFunctionName": "savePartitionedData1",

"saveFunctionDef": "           

def rowUpdate(dbName, tbName, data, t){              

  dfsPath = dbName
  temp = select * from t         
  update temp set trade_dt = datetimeParse(trade_dt,"yyyyMMdd")
  loadTable(dfsPath, tbName).append!(temp)}

def savePartitionedData1(dbName, tbName, data){              
  dfsPath = dbName
  login(\"admin\",\"123456\")
  t = loadTable(dfsPath, tbName)              
  ds1 = sqlDS(<select * from t>)
  mr(ds1, rowUpdate{dbName, tbName, data})         
} "
```

However, an error occurs: `Server response: 'savePartitionedData1: mr(ds1, rowUpdate{dbName, tbName, data}) => The type of some tuple elements is not DATASOURCE' function: 'savePartitionedData1{'dfs://stock_daily_TSDB','ashareeodprices'}'`.

How to solve this issue in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly update the data of the original table and use the `append!` function to append the data to a new table. Try not to use the `mr` function.